# Create test methods more quickly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I like to create my test methods like:

```
Should_not_allow_negative_number_in_value()
```

But it's pretty boring to keep typing _ every time, and it also has always the same signature...

so... anybody knows to make it faster??

thanks!

Comment: Is this question serious? If so, I don't understand what you mean. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Codemonkey What is wrong with this question? Of course it is serious. Is it so hard to understand that @Carol wants **to write methods where words are separated by _ without need of writing the _**? That could exist. For example, something that converts CamelCase naming to that one. Don't know.

Comment: I edited my question about naming. Don't know what I was thinking about. Take a look at it again..

Comment: thanks Oscar, I'm testing it here =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that might automate (not at all, but a little more if you use this naming notation) this process:

I usually name my tests like this:

`MethodToTest_State_ExpectedBehavior`

Example:

```
[Test]
public void ConvertToInt32_NullValue_ThrowException
{
    //Test method body
}
```

You can install ReSharper, and create a new *Live Template* like:

```
[Test]
public void $Method$_$State$_$Expected$()
{
    $END$
}
```

and asign a shortcut like **tst**.

Now, everytime you want to add a new method, you just need to start writing **tst** and press `TAB` two times, and it will create that method for you, placing the caret on the `Method` name. After you press `Enter`, the caret will move to the place you write the `State` name, then for the `Expected`, and then it will be placed where says `$END$`.

**Edit:**
That could be helpful too if you name all your tests with `_Should`. Something like:

`ConvertToInt32_NullValue_ShouldReturnTrue`

Then you can modify your template to:

```
[Test]
public void $Method$_$State$_Should$Expected$()
{
    $END$
}
```

You could even try to group your naming conventions into a few groups, and create a snippet/template for each of them.

**Edit 2:**
More about this test naming convention: [Naming Standards For Unit Tests](http://www.osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html), by Roy Osherove, author of *The Art Of Unit Testing*.

Answer (score 1):

use PascalCase instead of underscore_case

such as

```
ShouldNotAllowNegativeNumberInValue();
```

yay, no underscores! Code is now 80% less boring.

Comment: I think that is preference. I read CamelCasing just fine, and often better with long phrases such as that, because _ often push the length of such phrases off screen. You might want to consider adapting to CamelCase, esp with c# as that is the expected norm.

Comment: You really think that Carol? Every other method a developer encounters whether user code or framework code almost always precludes any underscores (with a few exceptions). What makes this unfamiliar way more readable for someone used to things being a different way?

Comment: ok.. I'll try, but I saw once in a webcast the test names being typed with spaces and after a return or something like that, it replaced the spaces for underscore...

Comment: Jamie, I mean, for test methods only

Comment: **I** like to name tests methods like @Carol. I think that is just a convention between programmers of your team, and how you feel more confortable about it. Besides, Roy Osherove, author of *The Art Of Unit Testing* likes that way too :/

Comment: @Oscar, I did say it was preference... However, I believe c# convention is to use CamelCasing. I know PHP tends to use underscore_casing instead. I follow the convention for the language, but meh.

Comment: Your example is PascalCase not camelCase.

Comment: @RonnieOverby thanks, I was just wondering this at work with some coworkers just yesterday! How timely

Answer (score 1):

Use shorter names and don't write sentences into a method name use something more like

```
DisallowNegativeValuesTest()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for readable tests, look into Cucumber & Gherkin as a BDD framework.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few options I know of for making this easier:
[Use AutoHotkey](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/17/spaces-in-identifier-names-in-c/) or
[Use ReSharper LiveTemplates](http://www.joaroyen.com/2010/08/resharpers-live-templates-can-do.html)